# Buck converter (LTC3330) voltage spikes in output voltage and in PGVOUT during transient

Tags: buck, spike

I am using Linear Technology LTC3330 (2048A evaluation board) buck converter with VIN thresholds set at 10V and 5V. The output set voltage is 3.3V. Inductor is 22uH. The input capacitor is 200uF and output is a 10mF supercapacitor. During charging of the output capacitor (transient time), whenever the input voltage rises above 10V, buck operation starts (as expected) and there is a large spike on the output voltage that reaches upto the set 3.3V and also for a brief time triggers the PGVOUT (boolean signal for output voltage reaching the set value).

The oscilloscope screenshot is attached. Can someone please suggest how to get rid of these spikes?

I have to integrate a microcontroller with PGVOUT as the wakeup signal. This spurious PGVOUT pulses during the transient (before VOUT reaches target 3.3V) will cause an issue. I have verified that spikes are not oscilloscope probe artifacts. It is also verified since the PGVOUT signal also goes high for the same period as spike so it's the output voltage that is spiking upto the target value (3.3V here).

Thank you.

[image: Oscilloscope screenshot showing input voltage. output voltage and PGVOUT]

Comment: Simulation or measurement? Part of the problem may be layout.

Answer (score 0):

Without going into a deeper analysis of the circuit, my first thought is that this problem might be happening due to a combination of 3 parts of the circuit.

1. The ESR of the 10 mF supercapacitor (and possibly the 200 uF capacitor? not sure..)
2. The high 200 uF input capacitor
3. The high 10V buck operation trip point vs the 3.3V output.

By charging such a large capacitor to 10V, it will take some time for all that energy to make it's way through the LTC3330 and into the supercapacitor due to the finite ESR of the 10 mF supercapacitor. During this time, the output voltage will be at its setpoint of 3.3V until the large input capacitor discharges enough to stop charging the supercapacitor.

Unless you can decrease the size of the input capacitor or decrease the 10V threshold, I think that there's nothing you can do to stop the LTC3330 from outputting a brief blip on PGVOUT every time your input capacitor charges to 10V.

However, one thing you could do is filter the output signal on PGVOUT using a simple low pass filter and comparator as shown in the circuit below. Just make sure to use a rail-to-rail output op-amp or comparator, and choose values of R and C appropriately to reject the short spikes you don't care about.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I understand the above circuit and it works. But what's the role of C2?